# Game doesnt understand mouse movements that are done by win32api or pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

i wanted to do a simple program that looks for "skip_button.png" on screen, if found, moves mouse to its coordinates and presses LMB, everything works fine but the mouse press. the problem is that the button is NOT clickable unless the game thinks you moved the mouse on it, when mouse is moved it will become slightly bigger and clickable, if i just move my mouse physically it obviously works, but if mouse is moved by pyautogui/autopy/win32api the game will do nothing, requiring me to move my physically in order to press the button. Its roblox by the way.

Is there any fixes to it?

```
import pyautogui as ag
import win32api, win32con
from time import sleep
import keyboard as kb
print(kb._os_keyboard.from_name)

def move(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
def click():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0,0)
    sleep(0.10)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0,0)
while True:
    sleep(1)
    res = ag.locateCenterOnScreen("C:/Users/YM/Desktop/python_vscode/tds_autoskip/skip_button.png", confidence=0.8)
    if res != None:
        x, y = res
        print(x,y)
        
        move(x,y)
        sleep(0.5)
        click()

    else:
        print("no find")
```

this is my code

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a solution for your problem which is make a small movement for the mouse:

```
import pyautogui as ag
import win32api, win32con
from time import sleep
import keyboard as kb
import random
print(kb._os_keyboard.from_name)

def move(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
def click():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0,0)
    sleep(0.10)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0,0)
while True:
    sleep(1)
    res = ag.locateCenterOnScreen("C:/Users/YM/Desktop/python_vscode/tds_autoskip/skip_button.png", confidence=0.8)
    if res != None:
        x, y = res
        print(x, y)
        
        move(x, y)
        sleep(0.5)
        # Simulate a small mouse movement
        move(x + random.randint(-1, 1), y + random.randint(-1, 1))
        sleep(0.1)
        click()

    else:
        print("no find")
```